# Asp.Net Core Mutex

Tags: c#, .net, mutex, .net-core

I have mutex:

```
_logger.Info("Step_1");
if (mutex.WaitOne())
{
    try
    {
       _logger.Info("Step_2");
       //Some tasks... 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex, "Mutex");
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
else
{
    _logger.Info("MutexError!");
}
```

mutex definition:

```cs
mutex = new Mutex(false, "ImportMutex", out createdNew);
```

In Step_1 I have 14 requests but the Step_2  reaches only 9 (This is only example sometimes its 10 or 8 requests reaches). Why? What I do wrong in this mutex?

Comment: Does the line `_logger.Info("MutexError!");` get logged?

Comment: Could you just use a regular lock? why are you using a Mutex?

Comment: `dcg` Nope. `caesay` You think it's better idea?